# Show the three best items in the pie chart and summarize the rest as Others

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I would like to have the number of items that appeared in a purchase shown in a circle diagram. Only the top 3 products should be listed as a whole and the rest should be summarized in `Other`.

```
   import pandas as pd
d = {'buyerid': [0,0,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
         'itemid': [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,4,5,0],
         'description': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Dog-Food', 'Beef', 'Banana',], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head(10))
    
purch = df['buyerid'].nunique()
df1 = df.groupby(['itemid','description']).size().div(purch).reset_index(name='percentage')
print (df1)
    
   itemid description  percentage
0       0      Banana         0.6
1       1       Apple         0.8
2       1  Strawberry         0.2
3       4    Dog-Food         0.2
4       5        Beef         0.2

df_top = df[['itemid', 'percentage']].head(5)
plot = df_top .plot.pie(y='percentage', figsize=(7, 7))
```

What I currently have

[image]

What I want
(Note, these data are only dumb. They have nothing in common with the above data. These data should only represent what I want)

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to show the pie chart for a single buyer? And, is apple with itemid 1 different from apple with itemid2? 
If so, could you leave out the buyerid column and provide more data instead so that your requirement of having "top 3" can be satisfied?

Comment: @Benedictanjw the pie chart is over all purchase. And my mistake (thanks for the hint). Apple should have the same id, please see my edit.

Comment: So what purpose does buyerid and itemid have in your data then? Could they be left out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I assume buyerid and itemid have no purpose, do take a look and see if it's what you want.

```py
d = {'itemid': [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,4,5,0],
'description': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Dog-Food', 'Beef', 'Banana',], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
ser = df.groupby('description')['itemid'].count()
### Combine categories
ser = ser.sort_values(ascending=False)
ser['Others'] = ser[3:].sum()
ser = ser.iloc[[0,1,2,-1]]
print(ser)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.pie(ser.values, labels=ser.index, startangle=90, autopct=lambda x:int(x/100.*ser.sum()), pctdistance=0.8, counterclock=False)
ax.legend()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]